# PHP MySQLi: variable issue

Tags: php, mysqli

I found a tshirt designer on github and have been working on it. I managed to get the customer function to insert into the database but it does not post the order details into the database. I get this error :

> Notice: Undefined variable: selectNumRows in G:\xampp\htdocs\tdesigner\php\send.php on line 73

Though when I check the code on line 73 and forth, I don't see any problems to it.

The function code:

```php
/* Get the number of rows and current customer information */
if ($selectCurrentCustomer = $mysqli->prepare($querySelect)) {
    /* Fetch the SELECT data */
    $selectCurrentCustomer->execute();
    $selectCurrentCustomer->bind_result($id);
    $selectCurrentCustomer->store_result();
    $selectCurrentCustomer->fetch();
    /* Store the customer ID and number of rows found */
    $selectNumRows = $selectCurrentCustomer->num_rows;
    $customerId = (selectNumRows == 0) ? $id : null;
    /* Close the query */
    $selectCurrentCustomer->close();
}

/* If not a returning customer, insert them into the database. Otherwise, update the existing customer */
if ($selectNumRows == 0) { //  LINE #73
```

I hope someone could help me on this. Thank you.

Comment: You're missing $ to the variable in the ternary check.

Comment: @PaulT. that should result in a different error though ~ _"Warning: Use of undefined constant selectNumRows - assumed 'selectNumRows'"_

Comment: Which line is #73? Also make sure you've exactly copy / pasted your code into your question

Comment: @Phil: ...that's likely correct, however, I have no idea what line 73 is in the posted code? ... the first thing that jumped out at me.

Comment: Is it [this file](https://github.com/StevenFrost/Apparel/blob/master/php/send.php#L73)? If so, you should set PDO to throw exceptions. My guess is the `prepare()` call is failing (silently), therefore `$selectNumRows` is never set and the **actual code** on line #73 is outside that `if` block

Comment: Also, as pointed out by @PaulT., you are missing a `$` before `selectNumRows`. If that isn't your Github project, I'd start filing some bugs

Comment: Thank you for the reply guys!! I appreciate it. Got it sorted out :)